# How to properly build a layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm kinda new with android programming and I can figure out many problems thanks to StackOverflow. But there's a thing where I keep struggle : Layouts.
I use DP as advised but it looks like it's not the ultimate solution.

See below, my XML code and what it [what it looks like on my Nexus 5X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG2RA.png) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.damien.dartscorer.MainActivity"
android:clipToPadding="false">




<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="#b71c1c"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/targe_mask"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/target"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointTextView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pressed_button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="315dp">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_x2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed_button"
            android:onClick="timesTwoClick"
            android:text="x2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#ffebee" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_25"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/halfb"
            android:elevation="9dp"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_missed"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/zero" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_50"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bull" />


        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_x3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pressed_button"
            android:onClick="timesThreeClick"
            android:text="x3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#ffebee" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Space>

    </LinearLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Player"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Player"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scoreC"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:text="Player"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scoreD"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:text="Player"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playerName1"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Pts" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playerName2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Pts" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Pts" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Pts" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/winLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DD000000">

    </View>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textColor="#FFEAED"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/winner" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_replay"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/winner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/replay" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_replay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home" />


</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see on this [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf7Sg.png), the layout sucks on a Pixel and yet, the screen don't have huge difference ! So how can I build something a minimum consistent ?

Also, I can't add elevation to my buttons and i don't really know why.

Thanks for helping,
Damien

Answer (score 0):

This is not how an Android XML layout should be, this code does not follow guidelines for UI development like parent and child elements. Please check some codes of XML layouts first then try developing with that.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:background="#b71c1c"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Some data"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_top"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="some other data"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is a sample code just try this and stud it by changing parameters

Comment: Thank you ! But I think I still need the frameLayout because my two imageViews need to be perfectly overlayed.

Comment: You can take whichever layout suits you but must follow the parent-child strategy to make the layout. Think of a full screen and first divide that layout into two to make your top part and bottom part, then make that top part of different sections so as to make the full view.